# Android - LayoutChange Animation for resize a View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout that contains some views...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/carSelectLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#C9C9C9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LogoFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CarCategoryFragment" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to change a view weight with animation? Somthing like `LayoutChanges` Animation...

**Edited:**

`LayoutChanges` Animation only works for add, remove or change visibilty of a view!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ValueAnimator and then add update listener where you change your layout parameters programaticly.

```
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 100);
            lp.weight = value;
            animatedView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
```

Comment: Thank you... It worked :)
But Still a problem! It only works for API 11 or higher! what can i do for lower APIs?

Comment: Please take a look at this examples http://nineoldandroids.com/ ..  

Android library for using the Honeycomb (Android 3.0) animation API on all versions of the platform back to 1.0!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check how to customize layout changes animation by taking a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html and the method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html#setAnimator(int, android.animation.Animator)